# BB Codes for about me section

Tags: support, markdown

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What HTML tags are allowed on Stack Exchange sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites)

From where I can find the BB codes to be used in the "About me" box in my profile?
If anyone have the list with them, please share.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: SO does not use "BBCode", it uses [Markdown](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stack Exchange sites use [Markdown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown)  as apposed to [BB code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bb_code) (Bulletin Board Code) which is mostly used for online forums. Markdown can be considered more readable then BB code, which makes editing less daunting.

A full guide to text formatting can be found [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help).